# Spark - Date vs Timestamp Comparison - nonsense results `2018-01-01` LESS than `2018-01-01 00:00:00`

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm running into a thing with Spark and comparing Dates with Timestamps and I just don't understand what's happening.

Here's the code to reproduce (pyspark)

```
query = '''with data as (
    select date('2018-01-01') as d
        , timestamp('2018-01-01') as t
)
select d < t as natural_lt
    , d = t as natural_eq
    , d > t as natural_gt
    , d < date(t) as cast_date_lt
    , d = date(t) as cast_date_eq
    , d > date(t) as cast_date_gt
    , timestamp(d) < t as cast_timestamp_lt
    , timestamp(d) = t as cast_timestamp_eq
    , timestamp(d) > t as cast_timestamp_gt
from data
'''
spark.sql(query).show()
```

And the results:

```
+----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|natural_lt|natural_eq|natural_gt|cast_date_lt|cast_date_eq|cast_date_gt|cast_timestamp_lt|cast_timestamp_eq|cast_timestamp_gt|
+----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|      true|     false|     false|       false|        true|       false|            false|             true|            false|
+----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

This completely violates my expectations.  We get that `"2018-01-01"` is LESS than `"2018-01-01 00:00:00"` -- obviously there nothing on this date before the time `00:00:00`, so I find this to be counter-intuitive.

I would expect either an exception (comparing date vs timestamp is ambiguous), or for it to compare them by casting or both to timestamp (treat `2018-01-01` as `2018-01-01 00:00:00` for the comparison).

Can anyone explain why this comparison is happening? More importantly, can I get Spark to behave according to my expectations? Can I get Spark to just throw an exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because both timestamp and date are downcast to string which leading to unexpected result.

Here is the Analyzed Logical Plan for your query:

```
 +- Project [(cast(d#46 as string) < cast(t#47 as string)) AS natural_lt#37, (cast(d#46 as string) = cast(t#47 as string)) AS natural_eq#38, (cast(d#46 as string) > cast(t#47 as string)) AS natural_gt#39, (d#46 < cast(t#47 as date)) AS cast_date_lt#40, (d#46 = cast(t#47 as date)) AS cast_date_eq#41, (d#46 > cast(t#47 as date)) AS cast_date_gt#42, (cast(d#46 as timestamp) < t#47) AS cast_timestamp_lt#43, (cast(d#46 as timestamp) = t#47) AS cast_timestamp_eq#44, (cast(d#46 as timestamp) > t#47) AS cast_timestamp_gt#45]
```

Jira : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23549 (Fix Version/s: 2.4.0)